# unique vector patterns are no longer supported

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, rust-0.9

I realize Rust is in flux, but I'm trying to learn it anyway.  I'm trying to understand how I would adapt the following example, which works with 0.9, into something similar that works with 0.10:

```rust
fn main() {
    let argv = std::os::args();

    let (first, last) = match argv {
        [_, first_arg, .., last_arg] => (first_arg, last_arg),
        _ => fail!("Error: At least two arguments expected.")
    };

    println!("The first argument was {:s}, \
              and the last argument was {:s}.", first, last); 
}
```

When I build this with 0.10, I get the following error:

```
error: couldn't read test.rc: no such file or directory (No such file or directory)
orflongpmacx8:rust pohl_longsine$ rustc test.rs
test.rs:9:9: 9:37 error: unique vector patterns are no longer supported
test.rs:9         [_, first_arg, .., last_arg] => (first_arg, last_arg),
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

My question:  is it still possible to use pattern matching on argv, but with different syntax, or is using a match statement on argv no longer possible at all?  If it's the former, what would I have to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still match on slices `&[T]` and fixed length arrays `[T, .. n]`. so, in this case,

```rust
fn main() {
    let argv = std::os::args();

    let (first, last) = match argv.as_slice() {
        [_, ref first_arg, .., ref last_arg] => (first_arg, last_arg),
        _ => fail!("Error: At least two arguments expected.")
    };

    println!("The first argument was {:s}, \
              and the last argument was {:s}.", *first, *last); 
}
```

Note the addition of the `ref`s. `argv` is `~[~str]`, i.e. the contents are owned strings `~str`, which move ownership when passed by value as a `[_, first_arg, .., last_arg]` pattern would do. It's illegal to move ownership out from behind a borrowed pointer (like a slice `&[~str]`) so that pattern would be illegal. One can borrow into the slice (and any other pattern) using the `ref` keyword, making `first` and `last` both references of type `&~str`.

One might wonder why the `*first` and `*last` dereferences aren't trying to move a `~str` out from behind a `&~str`, but it's because the `println!` macro is expanding to essentially `&*first` and `&*last`, which is fine.

(We could also write `=> (first_arg.as_slice(), last_arg.as_slice())` to borrow the two `&~str`s straight to string slices `&str`, which then means we don't need to dereference in the `println!`.)